# How to use CSS Transform to center a image on a mobile device?

Tags: css, transform

Does anyone know how to use the `transform` and `transform-origin` style in order to center the image on a small device? I want to keep the full screen of the image but I want to center and reduce the sides of the image when it goes on the phone device. I have tried to use this function on my image but it doesn't work...

```
.slide-image {
    transform: matrix3d(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
}
```

Here is a the HTML:

```
<!-- INTRO  -->

<div id="bootstrap-touch-slider" class="carousel bs-slider fade  control-round indicators-line" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="hover">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <a href="/la-creatrice" class="w3-animate-opacity">
            <div class="item active" >
                <img src="/images/intro/intro-1.png" class="slide-image"/>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="/images/intro/intro-2.png" class="slide-image"/>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="/images/intro/intro-3.png" class="slide-image"/>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="/images/intro/intro-4.png" class="slide-image"/>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>


    <!-- Controls -->
    <div class="control-box">
        <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        </a>
        <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        </a>
    </div>
    <script src="./javascripts/carousel-intro.js"></script>
```

This is the CSS I used :

```css
.bs-slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.bs-slider > .carousel-inner > .item {
     margin: auto;
     width: 100% !important;
     height: auto;
}

.bs-slider:hover {
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

.bs-slider:active {
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
```

And finally here is the JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000
    })
});
```

Comment: and why you think you have to use transform?

Comment: Is it possible with something else? I have searched a long time actually to try to find a solution for this lol and the closest solution I have found is by using a transform style...but if you have an easier solution I am right open !

Comment: we need more details about you code in order to give me advices

Comment: i think you should check what are media queries and flexbox

Comment: I have checked actually...but it doesn't make the effect I want because I want to cut the image and show only the center of the image full screen on small device. Maybe I haven't checked enough ?

Comment: You could possibly set a minimum height, position relative, and overflow hidden on the `.item` and then absolutely position the images in the center, or set the image src as a background image. If you start on one of these approaches and have questions I'd start a new question. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this method ! I will let you know